# How I can use emojis with React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I need to know if is there an emoji library that allows using of emojis and also gets an HTML emoji decimal or hexadecimal code to use as an HTML entity like `&#x1F3AF;` for 
I also want to retrieve a list of emojis codes too.

I want to render at a React component.

Could someone help me with some ideas?

Comment: Is this a bot post? This question doesn't make sense, Googling for "javascript emoji library" returns many results.

Comment: Sorry, English is not my first language, I am learning how to ask questions.

Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get you correctly, you want to find **full emoji references list.**

You can **check out** this emoji **unicode reference** from W3Schools: https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_emoji.asp

*Just surf the list and find the emoji you need. Copy* **the reference ( hexadecimal or decimal )** of that emoji and paste in html tag.
*If you still didn't get how to use the emojis with references, you can read instructions at* https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_emojis.asp.

*If it doesn't satisfy your needs*, try searching for more complex methods such as **emoji-picker-react** (also a simple guide with details https://www.npmjs.com/package/emoji-picker-react ) or any other library with its respective documentation.